# Google Maps API + Android Location Data

Tags: android, google-maps, geocode

For people who may already be doing this what is a good way to match a users location to a building or area using Google Maps? As in does the Google Maps API have a way to call up building locations/names which Google has already tagged so I don't have to go back and mark with some polygon certain areas. My use case is I have Android GPS data but I want to be able to say oh those lat,lon points are in building xyz by feeding them to the API. I am pretty sure the API supports this I'm just trying to understand what I should be searching for so I can find the appropriate guide/documentation to accomplish this.

Is there anything better than what's been suggested here:

[Google GeoCode - coordinates of the bulding [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106676/google-geocode-coordinates-of-the-bulding)

[Google maps - how to get building's polygon coordinates from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401661/google-maps-how-to-get-buildings-polygon-coordinates-from-address)

Or is there a way to give the API a lat,lon and it finds the building the user is closest to?

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult. Google Maps does not seem to have a built-in way of grabbing the actual building name rather than the address.

You could try using the FourSquare API.  We are combining that with actually mapping out polygon coordinates (although not quite scalable).  Or if you can get users to crowdsource information by checking in, that would be useful.