# Google Maps API: How to calculate the building surface area?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, surface, building, footprint

In google maps, we can see a building footprint displayed. But how can we get this building outlines details via the Google Maps API? I know you have an easy algorithm to calculate a surface area in m2 via maps, but there you have to put in your data points manually.

Is there a functionality in the API where you can get the building outline details?

I've spend some time looking for the functionality in the API, not finding it... If someone could give me a hint if this functionality exists or not, I know if I have to focus on image-processing :)

Thanks in advance!

[image: The surface a specific building]

Answer (score 4):

Here is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401661/google-maps-how-to-get-buildings-polygon-coordinates-from-address) on SO. Hope it will help.

**EDIT**

There is also another way of getting building coordinates. You can use data extracted from OSM http://www.openstreetmap.org.

1. Select area and export **.osm** file. 
   [image]
2. The file has **xml** structure. Inside you will find nodes with associated coordinates. Rest of the file usually contains objects which could be tagged as building. Objects are described by set of references to nodes so you will have to follow the references and find out coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this will lead me in the right direction.

Comment: @Shouse any luck? I'm also interested, so it would be great if you could update this answer with your findings.

Comment: Any update on this, I am also hitting the same issue and am stuck.

Comment: Any results?  I'm in the need as well.  The manual part is the time consuming part.  I'd like to fully automate this.  OSM option's data is too convoluted as I see it, and the zoom is less than Google.