# Extract building edges from map image using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I got a map image here.
I need to extract the edges of buildings for further process, the result would be like step 2 for the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401661/google-maps-how-to-get-buildings-polygon-coordinates-from-address).

Since I am not familiar with this field, can this be done by libraries such as OpenCV?

[image: map image]

Comment: The colors of buildings' boundary are easily distinguishable. So, I suppose this tutorial is helpful: https://realpython.com/python-opencv-color-spaces/

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Try [canny edge detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you want to select individual buildings, so I used color separation. The walls are darker, which makes for good separation in the [HSV colorspace](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html). Note that the final result can be improved by zooming in more and/or by using an imagetype with less compression, such as PNG.

**Select walls**
First I determined good values for separation. For that I used [this script](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator). I found that the best result would be to separate the yellow and the gray separately and then combine the resulting masks. Not all walls closed perfectly, so I improved the result by [closing](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) the mask a bit. The result is a mask that displays all walls:

[image]
*Left to right: Yellow mask, Gray mask, Combined and solidified mask*

**Find buildings**
Next I used [findCountours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#) to separate out buildings. Since the wall contours will probably not be very useful (as walls are interconnected), I used the [hierarchy](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) to find the 'lowest' contours (that have no other contours inside of them). These are the buildings.

[image]
*Result of findContours: the outline of all contours in green, the outline of individual buildings in red*

Note that buildings on the edge are not detected. This is because using this technique they are not a separate contour, but part of the exterior of the image. This can be solve this by drawing a [rectangle](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html#drawing-rectangle) in gray on the border of the image. You may not want this in your final application, but I included it in case you do.

**Code:**

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np  

    #load image and convert to hsv
    img = cv2.imread("fLzI9.jpg")

    # draw gray box around image to detect edge buildings
    h,w = img.shape[:2]
    cv2.rectangle(img,(0,0),(w-1,h-1), (50,50,50),1)

    # convert image to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define color ranges
    low_yellow = (0,28,0)
    high_yellow = (27,255,255)

    low_gray = (0,0,0)
    high_gray = (179,255,233)

    # create masks
    yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_yellow, high_yellow )
    gray_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_gray, high_gray)

    # combine masks
    combined_mask = cv2.bitwise_or(yellow_mask, gray_mask)
    kernel = np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.uint8)
    combined_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(combined_mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE,kernel)

    # findcontours
    contours, hier = cv2.findContours(combined_mask,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # find and draw buildings
    for x in range(len(contours)):
            # if a contour has not contours inside of it, draw the shape filled
            c = hier[0][x][2]
            if c == -1:
                    cv2.drawContours(img,[contours[x]],0,(0,0,255),-1)

    # draw the outline of all contours
    for cnt in contours:
            cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),2)

    # display result
    cv2.imshow("Result", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result:**
*With buildings drawn solid red and all contours as green overlay*

[image]

Comment: Hi J.D., this is just perfect for me not only because it solved my problem but the references help a lot as well (that HSV colorspace scripts is awesome), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach

- Convert image to grayscale and Gaussian blur to smooth edges
- Threshold image
- Perform Canny edge detection
- Find contours and draw contours

Threshold image using [`cv2.threshold()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

[image]

Perform Canny edge detection with [`cv2.Canny()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html)

[image]

Find contours using [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) and `cv2.drawContours()`

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 240 ,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
canny = cv2.Canny(thresh, 50, 255, 1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image,[c], 0, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('canny.png', canny)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```